# How to allow anonymous access to solr metrics endpoint?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to get the solr prometheus exporter to scrape a solr service that has authentication enabled. But the /admin/metrics endpoint can't be accessed by prometheus exporter without authenticating.
We are ok with allowing anonymous access to the metrics endpoint, while having all other apis closed. Is there a way to do this?

Solr version is 8.4. JWT auth plugin is used with an external idp.